# ad blocker which blocks the ad, but makes the receiving party mark the ad as watched?

Tags: windows, ad-blocker, advertising

I was wondering if there is any ad blocker that still blocks the add, but makes the receiving ad party thinks the ad is being watched (and so generates income). I want to support some websites, bud I don't want adds.

Is there something for this that runs on Windows (Android would be nice as well) and costs $50 max?

Comment: One note from an ethics standpoint: What you are looking for is essentially an advertising fraud tool.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly as requested, but you can try the [Brave](https://brave.com/) browser. It is based on Chromium, it has embedded ad blocker, anti-tracking, Tor browsing and other privacy measures. It allows you to anonymously reward content creators based on amount of time you've spend on their resources, as a compensation for lost ad revenues. You can also tip your favorite creators, also anonymously. Wikipedia, DuckDuckGo and many others are already accepting these Brave rewards and tips.

Comment: Before choosing Brave, do look into their history. They've had several instances of borderline unethical behavior including one with auto-completion giving referral links (https://zephyrnet.com/brave-browser-faces-heat-from-users-amidst-referral-link-autofill-scandal/), and another where they were automatically collecting money for creators who never signed up for any such thing (https://beincrypto.com/youtuber-lashes-out-at-brave-for-receiving-bat-donations-in-his-name-without-his-consent/). Basically, these guys are a bit shady in my opinion, and I would be careful about trusting them.

Comment: @MichaelKohne the second case looks to me like a misunderstanding about how Brave works. It does not "collect money for creators who never signed up". The browser measures time spent by you on each website and tries to allocate your monthly limit of tokens to spend according to the ratio of attention each site received. But if some site creators have not opted in (i.e. didn't explicitly create their creator's accounts), then tokens allocated to them will remain unclaimed and return back to the user. Only those creators who registered and verified receive tokens and can convert them to money.

Comment: @Bronx "has been using his name and photo to collect cryptocurrency donations" seems clearly unethical even if they skipped "stealing money" part. Though note that they stopped this practice and name/photo was used because it was used as name and image of YT channel.

Comment: Also, Brave had large scale ad campaign appearing in many ads. Even if they stopped that it is sufficient for me to avoid them if at all possible.

Comment: @reducingactivity It is unethical to spread misinformation based on an internet article lacking facts and understanding. Brave haven't been "using his name and photo to collect cryptocurrency donations". If doesn't work this way.

Comment: @Bronx Article mentions that they changed this, and I mentioned it. I am not claiming and aricle is not claiming and Michael is not claiming that it is CURRENTLY working this way. But it used to work this way.

If this article is missing "facts and understanding" - can you be more specific what is missing?

Comment: @reducingactivity Brave never worked this way, and nothing changed in its principles since the beginning. There was no such thing as "*a page that ‘advertised’ Scott as a content creator, .. assumed Scott created the page or, at least, gave his consent*". The author confused it with a popup for sending tips to a creator, which shows youtuber's public info from the currently visited YT channel page. Claiming it is unethical is like claiming same about a browser's SSL certificate popup showing public info (domain, company name). The tips UI is not to push own services to users, it is to inform.

Comment: @Bronx Showing something as "tipping UI" with stream image (in this case - their face) and stream name (in this case - their name) and allowing to transfer money supposedly to them is exactly "automatically collecting money for creators who never signed up for any such thing" and "using his name and photo to collect cryptocurrency donations" and misusing identify of someone who never agreed to this scheme.

Unless it would be very clearly marked that tips will not reach that person and entire scheme is not endorsed by that person - and as article documents it was not true.

Comment: @reducingactivity It is no way "automatically collecting money", because Brave Rewards are opt-out by default. No rewards are earned or sent until you explicitly enable it, and while doing so you're informed about the reward mechanics, about a difference between "unverified" and "verified" creators, about how tokens are delivered (or not) and so on. The fact that "verified/unverified" tag didn't appear in a tipping UI while the feature was still in a beta stage is a pretty minor detail, that was exaggerated and mispresented as a "shady scheme like opt-in by default". **That** is unethical.

Comment: @Bronx ""verified/unverified" tag didn't appear in a tipping UI while the feature was still in a beta stage" - that WAS a "shady scheme like opt-in by default". Fortunately they get rid of it after backslash, so they are not ethically bankrupt but it was actually deployed.

Comment: @reducingactivity There was no "opt-in by default", hence there was no such scheme.